# Joined column is null for OneToMany relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to create a Hotel Room relationship where in post call I am trying to pass rooms array . Hoping to save the room in controller . 
The problem i am facing right now is when i call /newhotel, a hotel is saved and it's associated rooms get saved. But those rooms have their hotel_id NULL. Why the association was not created at the time of saving the room ?

```
public class Hotel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hotel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Room> rooms;

}

public class Room {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "hotel_id")
    private Hotel hotel;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoomType roomType;
}

@RestController
public class HotelController {
    @Autowired
    HotelRepository hotelRepository;
    @Autowired
    RoomRepository roomRepository;
    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(value = "/newhotel")
    public Hotel addHotel(@RequestBody Hotel hotel) {
        return hotelRepository.save(hotel);
    }
}
```

Below is my post call request body :

```
{
    "name" : "hotel1",
    "rooms" : [
              {
                "roomType" : "SingleBed"
              } 
    ]
}
```

Comment: @JoinColumn(name = "room_id", nullable = false) . make it nullable true.
after that dont forget to update your table

Comment: @sajib but the hotel_id is coming null.when i am querying select * from room; when it should be the same as newly created hotel's id

Comment: @user2991413 You can check my answer !